# Configuring multiple Jenkins agents that use the same workspace folder

Tags: jenkins

Is it a good practice to have multiple Jenkins agents that use **the same workspace folder** ("Remote root directory") (i.e. from the storage on the network)?
Would jobs run properly or are problems to be expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it. Multiple concurrent builds would be overwriting each other. One might be trying to compile, while the other deletes the whole source tree and checks out a fresh copy.